# How handle Varbinary an asp.net update

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In an ASP.NET form I have a ListView control in which one of the columns is a `Varbinaty(max)` value.

The problem is when I try to handle this value.

Following the select:

```
SELECT CODICE_ARTICOLO, DESCRIZIONE, UM, FOTO, TIPO_ART FROM TBL_ARTICOLI
```

where `FOTO` is `Varbinary(max)`.

This is the `UPDATE` command:

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [TBL_ARTICOLI] SET [DESCRIZIONE] = @DESCRIZIONE, [UM] = @UM, [FOTO] = @FOTO, [TIPO_ART] = @TIPO_ART WHERE [CODICE_ARTICOLO] = @CODICE_ARTICOLO">

        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="DESCRIZIONE" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UM" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="FOTO" Type="Object" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="TIPO_ART" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CODICE_ARTICOLO" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
```

When I try to update the item I get the following error:

> *La conversione implicita del tipo di dati da sql_variant a
>   varbinary(max) non è consentita. Per eseguire la query, utilizzare la
>   funzione CONVERT.*

In English it is telling to me that it cannot convert from `sql_variant` to `varbynary(max)`, but if I'm using the conversion like it:

```
[FOTO] = CAST(@FOTO AS VARBINARY(MAX))
```

I'm getting the following error:

> *I dati di tipo string o binary verrebbero troncati. L'istruzione è
>   stata interrotta.*

So string or binary would be truncated the command was interrupted.

I tried to convert the `varbinary` in hex string but every time I'm getting the last error.

Somebody can help me ?

Thank you

Piercarlo

Answer (score 2):

Try to use SqlBinary as the type?  (Not sure, and no access to a dev machine atm.)

```
<asp:Parameter Name="FOTO" Type="SqlBinary" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest here is,try to create a sproc in sql server to update the varbinary fields.And from asp.net just pass the parameters to sproc and for varbinary field just use the string datatype in asp.net.I mean assign the value to the string datatype and pass it to the sproc.

Now sproc will update the required fields in the table.