# SQL VARBINARY IN ASP.NET UPDATE

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How handle Varbinary an asp.net update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560046/how-handle-varbinary-an-asp-net-update)

Hi this is the following of my previous question.

The problem is when I'm tryng to update a varbinary filed by one listview in an aspx form.
Every time I retrieve the same error:

I dati di tipo string o binary verrebbero troncati. L'istruzione è stata interrotta. So string or binary would be truncated the command was interrupted.

I tougth that was problem of asp.net and I tried to do across server side with c# intercepting the event ItemInserting of the list view with following code:

RunSqlCommand is a class that i made on bottom the code:

```
        protected void ListView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        IOrderedDictionary NuoviValori = e.NewValues;
        Label CodiceArticolo = (Label)ListView1.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("CODICE_ARTICOLOLabel1");
        string Descrizione = "";
        string UM = "";
        string Foto = "";
        string TipoArt = "";
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in NuoviValori)
        {
            switch (entry.Key.ToString())
            {
                case "DESCRIZIONE":
                    Descrizione = entry.Value.ToString();
                    break;
                case "UM":
                    UM = entry.Value.ToString();
                    break;
                case "FOTO":
                    if (entry.Value == null)
                    {
                        Foto = EncodeTo64("ADBC"); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Foto = entry.Value.ToString();
                    }
                    break;
                case "TIPO_ART":
                    TipoArt = entry.Value.ToString();
                    break;
            }
        }
        e.Cancel = true;
        string strCmd = "UPDATE TBL_ARTICOLI SET DESCRIZIONE = '" + Descrizione +"'," +
                                               "UM = '" + UM +"'," +
                                               "FOTO = @Foto," + 
                                               "TIPO_ART = '" + TipoArt + "' " +
                                               "WHERE CODICE_ARTICOLO = '" + CodiceArticolo.Text + "'";
        RunSqlCommand.Parametro parametro = new RunSqlCommand.Parametro();
        parametro.Name = "Foto";
        parametro.Tipo = SqlDbType.VarBinary;
        parametro.Value = Convert.FromBase64String(Foto);
        RunSqlCommand.Parametro[] Parametri = new RunSqlCommand.Parametro[1];
        Parametri[0] = parametro;
        string retCmd = new RunSqlCommand().RunSqlCmdParamDeltaSSL(strCmd, Parametri);
        ListView1.EditIndex = -1;
    }

        static public string EncodeTo64(string toEncode)
    {
        byte[] toEncodeAsBytes
              = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);
        string returnValue
              = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
        return returnValue;
    }

    public struct Parametro
    {
        public SqlDbType Tipo;
        public object Value;
        public string Name;
    }


        public string RunSqlCmdParamDeltaSSL(string Command, Parametro[] Parameters)
    {
        int NumeroAffetto;
        Connection ConnString = new Connection();
        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection();
        Conn.ConnectionString = ConnString.ConnectDeltaSSL();
        SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand(Command, Conn);
        foreach (Parametro param in Parameters)
        {
            SqlParameter picparameter = new SqlParameter();
            picparameter.SqlDbType = param.Tipo;
            picparameter.ParameterName = param.Name;
            picparameter.Value = param.Value;
            Comando.Parameters.Add(picparameter);
        }
        Comando.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        try
        {
            Comando.Connection.Open();
            NumeroAffetto = Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return NumeroAffetto.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            Comando.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

But with this code is thesame everytime the same mistake.

I controlled the table but the all is correct.

Really I dont know what need to do more.

Thankyou

Piercarlo

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a resolution that is following:
I made two function in sql server that convert varbinary in strinBase64 e viceversa in this way I can handle data like a string in asp.net:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION dbo.FUN_BASE64_TO_VARBINARY
    (
        @str VARCHAR(MAX)
    )
    RETURNS varbinary(max)
    AS
    BEGIN
    RETURN  cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@str"))', 'varbinary(max)');
    END

    ALTER FUNCTION dbo.FUN_BINARY_TO_BASE64
    (
        @bin varbinary(MAX)
    )
    RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
    AS
    BEGIN
        return cast(N'' as  xml).value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@bin")))', 'varchar(max)');
    END
```

and use it in the select and in the update commad as follow:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT CODICE_ARTICOLO, DESCRIZIONE, UM, dbo.FUN_BINARY_TO_BASE64(FOTO) AS FOTO, TIPO_ART FROM TBL_ARTICOLI
                       WHERE (SUBSTRING(CODICE_ARTICOLO, 1, CHARINDEX('*', CODICE_ARTICOLO) - 1) = @CATEGORIA_ARTICOLO)" 
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [TBL_ARTICOLI] SET [DESCRIZIONE] = @DESCRIZIONE, [UM] = @UM, [FOTO] = dbo.FUN_BASE64_TO_VARBINARY(@FOTO), [TIPO_ART] = @TIPO_ART WHERE [CODICE_ARTICOLO] = @CODICE_ARTICOLO">
```

The all work fine

Piercarlo